# jquery drop down box with search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My projects requires that I need a drop down box with search button .I created one but its working only for the first time .The issue  is I am making the other  items empty if search match is found .So the next click since other items are empty its not working. How should I solve this so that all the items appear first time and only the matching item appears  every time a match appears.Please help me.How should I fix it?
I have tried a lot  on this ,.This is my code.

**html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.sel-box{
position:relative;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
#select{
display:block;
width:235px;
height:20px;
border:1px solid #999;
padding:5px;
}
.toc-odd{
position:absolute;
top:32px;
background:#f1f1f1;
width:400px;
display:none;
}
.toc-odd li{
padding:5px 10px;
border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
</style>
 <body>
  <p id ="demo"></p>

  <div class="sel-box">
 <span id='select'>Select</span>
 <ul class='toc-odd level-1' id="sel-option">
 </body>
</html>
```

**script**

```
$(function() {
    $('#select').click(function() {
      $('#sel-option').show();
      var x = $("#sel-option .my_div").text();
      $("#demo").html(x);

    });

    $('#sel-option a').click(function() {
      $('#select').text($(this).text());
      $('#sel-option').hide();
      $(this).addClass('current');
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  })


  var employees = [{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
  }, ];
document.write("<div class=my_div>");
document.write("<li>" + "<input type=text id=searchTXT name=firstName >" + "<" + "button id=button1" + ">" + "Search " + "</button>");
document.write("</div>");
for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
  document.write("<div class=" + employees[i].firstName + ">");
  document.write("<li>" + "<a href=" + employees[i].firstName + ">" + employees[i].firstName + "</a>" + "</li>");
  document.write("</div>");
}

document.write("</ul>");

$("#sel-option button").click(function() {

  var x = $("#sel-option input").val();

  for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (x != employees[i].firstName) {
      $("." + employees[i].firstName).empty();
    }

  }

})
```

Comment: offtopic: do you seriously not format your CSS at all? Tabs? No?

Comment: sorry ?  i didnt understand ur question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must recreate your dropdown box, for this dont use document.write, but..
**REEDIT**

```
<p id ="demo"></p>
<div class="sel-box">
   <span id='select'>Select</span>
   <ul class='toc-odd level-1' id="sel-option"></ul>
   <div class="my_div">
       <input type=text id=searchTXT name=firstName/>
        <button id=btnSearch>Search</button>
        <div id="myDropDown"></div>
   </div>
</div>    

<script>
function createDropDown(){
   htm = "" 
   for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
       htm += "<div class=" + employees[i].firstName + ">";
       htm += "<li>" + "<a href=" + employees[i].firstName + ">" + employees[i].firstName + "</a>" + "</li>";
       htm += "</div>"
      $("#myDropDown").html(htm)  
    }
}    

createDropDown()

$("#btnSearch").click(function() {
  console.log("click..")  
  createDropDown()
  var x = $("input#searchTXT").val();
  for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (x != employees[i].firstName) {
      $("." + employees[i].firstName).empty();
      console.log("empty " + x)  
    }

  }

}) 


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply.But it says.."Uncaught ReferenceError: htm is not defined ".How to proceed ? please help